# How to cope with big files on Android

Tags: android

I have been developing application that needs 45 MB raw data file.

I have tried to add (45MB) file to resources (R.raw) - the project doesn't load into device due to memory limitations.

I read that Android market limits maximum application size to 50 MB, so there is a way to cope with big files.

I'm wondering, where should I store big files and how to use it ?

Comment: Have you tried to put it in `assets` directory?

Answer (score 1):

I have put files in assets directory - it solves the problem.